# How to make a naive datetime aware with dateutil.tz?

Tags: python, timezone, python-dateutil

Currently if I want to convert a naive `datetime` to an aware one, I do it as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

pytz_tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/London')

naive_datetime = datetime(2020, 1, 5, 10, 12)
aware_datetime = pytz_tz.localize(naive_datetime)
```

If instead I use `dateutil` as my timezone like so:

```
from dateutil import tz

dateutil_tz = tz.gettz('Europe/London')
```

How can I make the conversion with the `dateutil_tz` from naive to aware now?

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46735910/is-this-the-right-way-to-set-a-timezone-with-dateutil) post, but did not understand form it how it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since `dateutil` uses the same timezone model as the `datetime` lib, you can set the `tzinfo` property straight away. You can also use `.replace(tzinfo=...)` safely.

```
import dateutil
aware_datetime = datetime(2020, 1, 5, 10, 12, tzinfo=dateutil.tz.gettz('Europe/London'))

print(aware_datetime)
# 2020-01-05 10:12:00+00:00
```

By the way, the procedure is identical if you use the `zoneinfo` module on Python 3.9:

```
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
aware_datetime = datetime(2020, 1, 5, 10, 12, tzinfo=ZoneInfo('Europe/London'))
```

Comment: Time to upgrade to `3.9` : ) Thanks!

Comment: @Newskooler: yep, about time that Python's standard lib handles timezones ;-) I guess some months will pass until 3.9 comes out of beta - until then, there is `backports`...

Comment: I will google `backports`. I have not heard of it...
Now if they re-think the module version control to be more like `nix`, it will be a whole new python :  )